# Vscode+Qemu+TinyOS Can‘t Using GUI gdb

Tags: gdb, qemu, vscode-debugger

I am setting up a tiny OS  followed this tutorial under Ubuntu18.04 http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/ .

So far I was able to compile and run the tiny kernel  in QEMU. and also being able to connect the gdb-server using the command line gdb.

```
qemu -S -s -fda floppy.img -boot a &
sleep 1
cgdb -x scripts/gdbinit
```

But  I would like to use  Vscode gdb GUI instead of  command line gdb， so I search this page https://wiki.osdev.org/User:TheCool1Kevin/VSCode_Debug to set up json file.
Here is my launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch with GDB",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/boot/boot.o",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [],
            "targetArchitecture": "x86",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "",
            "miDebuggerArgs": "",
            "customLaunchSetupCommands": [],
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "text": "file ${workspaceRoot}/cmy_kernel",
                    "description": "Load binary."
                },
                {
                    "text": "target remote :1234",
                    "description": "connect the port"
                },
                {
                    "text": "break kern_entry",
                    "description": "Break on exception handler."
                },
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Launch QEMU"
        }
    ]
}
```

And my task.json is

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Launch QEMU",
      "type": "shell",
      "windows": {
          "command": ""
      },
      "linux": {
          "command": "qemu -S -s -fda floppy.img -boot a &sleep 1 &"
      }
  }
  ]
}
```

I expect to be able to debug the the code under the VScode ,but when I start debug,   VScode shows that **Unable to connect the server :1234 timeout.**

I don't konw how to modify the file .Any suggestion of using extensions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this vs extension https://github.com/WebFreak001/code-debug

Since the -s command deploys a server or port:1234
You can use this configuration to attach it.

```
{
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "attach",
            "target": "localhost:1234",
            "remote": true,
            "gdbpath": "gdb",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "valuesFormatting": "parseText",
 }
```